# Integration of SceneBuilder with java Netbeans

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I am using: Window 10 (64-bit)

NetBeans 8.0.2

SceneBuilder 8.5.0

I installed SceneBuilder downloaded from official website. When I go to Options>Java>JavaFX and set SceneBuilder path to the installed directory C:\Users\Usman\AppData\Local\SceneBuilder , I get the error:

```
Selected location does not represent a valid JavaFX Scene Builder installation
```

Kindly guide me.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to post a question you should bring a minimum information as a input sample and expected output sample (if needed), what did you try and your research, in order to show some effort, as SO is not a free coding service. What did you try?

Comment: Did you install scenebuilder. It sounds like you dragged the installer somewhere. You actually need to install SceneBuilder. It's an external program, if used this way and in general you cannot just drag the executables of a installed program around, since they rely often rely on being stored in the location where you installed them. (The [SceneBuilder webpage](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download) lists installers only which seems to confirm my suspicion; Netbeans iirc doesn't allow you to specify a jar)

Comment: @fabian i installed the Scenebuilder but same error